# Why does this 3D CSS overlap instead of clip?

Tags: css, 3d

Why do these 3D CSS planes overlap in Firefox and Chrome and not in Safari?

http://jsfiddle.net/yNfQX/6/

..and how do I make it behave like safari?

**Safari & Firefox Preview**

[image: Safari Looks like this]
[image: Firefox Looks like this]

Comment: Interactive version to understand what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/yNfQX/21/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug...  from https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689498:

> Bug 689498 - Intersecting planes are not z-ordered properly
>
> Alistair MacDonald 2012-04-12 12:22:25 PDT Safari & Mobile Safari no
>   longer have this problem. The problem still exists in Chrome and
>   Firefox.
>
> Broken: Firefox 14.0a1 (2012-04-12) -Win7 Broken: Chrome 20.0.1096.1
>   -Win7 Fixed : Safari 5.1.5 (75.34.55.3) -Win7 Fixed : Mobile Safari (last updated over a month ago) -iOs
>
> Link to test-case and screen-grabs:
>   http://f1lt3r.com/code/3d-css-transforms-intersecting-planes-not-clipping/

Comment: There are two bug reports on Chromium also: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102673    http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116710

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it isn't too long for this to be fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing a bunch of websites will be broken, unfortunately, once this is fixed. I'm **on Chrome 26 and it still hasn't been fixed**.