# Chrome 3D CSS transform intersections not rendering properly

Tags: css, google-chrome, 3d, css-transforms

I'm trying to recreate this 3D effect as seen on the [W3 website.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/)[image]

I've put the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNafs/) but as you can see, the transforms have been applied but the intersection effect is not rendering properly. It doesn't work in Firefox either.

Is this a problem with Chrome, or a problem with the code?

```
    <style>
.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 500px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.container > :first-child {
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
    background-color: orange;
    top: 10px;
    height: 135px;
}
.container > :last-child {
    transform: translateZ(40px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);
    top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added to the fiddle a base layer, that rotates in the x axis on hover, just to make clear that the layout is indeed correct. Looks like a bug in Chrome. modified fiddle:  [http://jsfiddle.net/vals/uNafs/1/] confirmed bug track [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116710]

Comment: @vals your links are getting mangled by the closing ]'s

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this 3D CSS overlap instead of clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756922/why-does-this-3d-css-overlap-instead-of-clip)

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [Why does this 3D CSS overlap instead of clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756922/why-does-this-3d-css-overlap-instead-of-clip) ... According to that question it's a reported bug in webkit: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689498:

> Bug 689498 - Intersecting planes are not z-ordered properly
>
> Alistair MacDonald 2012-04-12 12:22:25 PDT Safari & Mobile Safari no
>   longer have this problem. The problem still exists in Chrome and
>   Firefox.
>
> Broken: Firefox 14.0a1 (2012-04-12) -Win7 Broken: Chrome 20.0.1096.1
>   -Win7 Fixed : Safari 5.1.5 (75.34.55.3) -Win7 Fixed : Mobile Safari (last updated over a month ago) -iOs
>
> Link to test-case and screen-grabs:
>   http://f1lt3r.com/code/3d-css-transforms-intersecting-planes-not-clipping/